How to use .asm in EDK2?
I am trying to use assembly in EDK2. I build an X64 driver so I can't use inline assembly but I always get an error while trying to compile.
I am using a HeciTool.asm that only returns a 0:
section .text

global AsmMain
AsmMain:
    mov rax, 0
    ret

This is my .inf:
[Defines]
    INF_VERSION = 0x00010005
    BASE_NAME = HeciTool
    FILE_GUID = 8E7F9C7F-F926-48A0-8642-0A882F408CC6
    MODULE_TYPE = UEFI_DRIVER
    VERSION_STRING = 1.0
    ENTRY_POINT = UefiMain

[Sources.X64]
    Std.c
    Main.c
    HeciTool.c
    Std.h
    HeciTool.h
    HeciTool.asm

[Packages]
    MdePkg/MdePkg.dec
    SharkBayRcPkg/SharkBayRcPkg.dec

[LibraryClasses]
    UefiLib
    IoLib
    BaseMemoryLib
    UefiDriverEntryPoint
    UefiBootServicesTableLib

[Protocols]
    gEfiSpiProtocolGuid
    gEfiSimpleTextInputExProtocolGuid

And this is my Main.c:
#include "HeciTool.h"

extern UINT64 ReturnNumber();

EFI_STATUS EFIAPI UefiMain(IN EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, IN EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable) {

    return AsmMain();

}

The compiler always throws an error:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x64\link.exe" /OUT:d:\edk2\HeciToolPkg\Build\RELEASE_VS2019\X64\HeciToolPkg\HeciTool\DEBUG\HeciTool.dll /NOLOGO /NODEFAULTLIB /IGNORE:4001 /IGNORE:4281 /IGNORE:4254 /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF=10 /MAP /ALIGN:32 /SECTION:.xdata,D /SECTION:.pdata,D /Machine:X64 /LTCG /DLL /ENTRY:_ModuleEntryPoint /SUBSYSTEM:EFI_BOOT_SERVICE_DRIVER /SAFESEH:NO /BASE:0 /DRIVER /MERGE:.rdata=.data /WHOLEARCHIVE  @d:\edk2\HeciToolPkg\Build\RELEASE_VS2019\X64\HeciToolPkg\HeciTool\OUTPUT\static_library_files.lst
HeciTool.lib(Main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned __int64 __cdecl ReturnNumber(void)" (?ReturnNumber@@YA_KXZ)
d:\edk2\HeciToolPkg\Build\RELEASE_VS2019\X64\HeciToolPkg\HeciTool\DEBUG\HeciTool.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x64\link.exe"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.


build.py...
 : error 7000: Failed to execute command
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x86\nmake.exe /nologo tbuild [d:\edk2\HeciToolPkg\Build\RELEASE_VS2019\X64\HeciToolPkg\HeciTool]


build.py...
 : error F002: Failed to build module
        d:\edk2\HeciToolPkg\HeciTool.inf [X64, VS2019, RELEASE]

What can I do to fix this?

Why did you use ReturnNumber if your function is called AsmMain?

My bad, I had changed some stuff in my code and forgot to change the function name

What's HeciTool.c? Note it's a bad idea to reuse the same basename for different files since both HeciTool.asm and HeciTool.c might try to create HeciTool.obj.

HeciTool.c is just a file where I got all my functions that are not Uefimain, I removed that from Main.c for this post so it looks better. I fixed it by renaming the .asm file, now it works. Thanks a lot
